# Adding Initial Velocity in the Game Engine

Tags: game-engine

I am creating a gravity simulation where a an object is moving and is caught by another object and goes into orbit around it. The problem is that since I am an absolute noob in the game engine, I don't know how to give the object an initial velocity that allows it to go into orbit, rather than just colliding with the other object. Could someone help with that?

I have included a picture of the scene below. Sorry for being a noob. Thanks

[image]

Comment: [https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=velocity#bge.types.KX_GameObject.setLinearVelocity](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=velocity#bge.types.KX_GameObject.setLinearVelocity)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a force to the object by activating an motion actuator.

Ensure the actuator deactivates after applying the initial force (or velocity).
 [image]

When you are working with dynamically added objects it is even simpler. You can set up an initial velocity of the added object.

[image]